# Cannot get availabe products information using PHP Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to get some information from this web page: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Front-strut-spacers-30mm-for-Ford-Focus2-C-Max-Focus3-Kuga-Escape-Lift-Kit/112460641185?epid=19025000547&hash=item1a2f2d33a1:g:0IYAAOSw1m9atFcz. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I want to extract the "10 available" info and I am using the span id `qtySubTxt`, however my code does not reach the actual value. Here is my code:

```
   $available = $html->find("#qtySubTxt", 0);
            //var_dump($available);
            if($available != null){
                $item['available'] = $available->plaintext;
            }else{
                $item['available'] = '';
            }
```

I debugged the DOM element but I am confused how to reach the text. Here is my debugged info from the DOM element:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "my code does not reach the actual value" ? what is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I am not getting "10 available" info

Comment: Ok what are you getting? empty string or what?

Comment: empty string because of the zero info in that object

Comment: Somehow I need to access object #6771 from above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I rewrtie your code using [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)  and everything works just fine.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://www.ebay.com/itm/Front-strut-spacers-30mm-for-Ford-Focus2-C-Max-Focus3-Kuga-Escape-Lift-Kit/112460641185?epid=19025000547&hash=item1a2f2d33a1:g:0IYAAOSw1m9atFcz");
$available  = $doc->getElementById("qtySubTxt");

if($available != null){
    $item['available'] = trim($available->nodeValue);
}else{
    $item['available'] = '';
}

print_r($item);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [available] => 10 available
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `$available = $html->getElementById("qtySubTxt");
                //var_dump($available);                 
                if($available != null){
                    $available->tagName; // span
                    $item['available']= $available->nodeValue;
                    var_dump($item['available']);`

Comment: I rewrite my code using yours but my value `$item['available']` is still Null

Comment: I`ve already loaded my web page and I only use the search part of your code

Comment: @IcoVladimirov Then check $sold variable, because i don't know where that variable is coming from!

Comment: Probably you're getting empty result because $sold is actually null in your if condition.

Comment: Yes the variable is `$available`, look at the code which I posted above in my comment

Comment: @IcoVladimirov I edited my code just like yours and it works.

Comment: `$available = $html->getElementById("qtySubTxt");` The problem is that in my case the `$html` dom element does not find the id, it return null.

Comment: I load the web page before that in that element

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202343/discussion-between-ico-vladimirov-and-fatalerror).